# Add, remove row from table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

According to my code I have 2 tables. On click of 'add' the whole row will append to the next table and on click of 'delete' it will append to the first table.

The code which I wrote works fine but I have a weird error on adding all rows or deleting all rows multiple times, as it will stop working. I am not able to figure out the issue.

```js
$(".addRow").on("click", function() {
  var $delete = '<h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;"></h4>';
  var $clone = $(this).parent().parent();
  $clone.find(".addRow").remove();
  $clone.find("td:eq(0)").append($delete);
  $(".selected table").append($clone);
  $(".deleteRow").on("click", function() {
    var $add = '<h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer"></h4>';
    var newClone = $(this).parent().parent();
    newClone.find(".deleteRow").remove();
    newClone.find("td:eq(0)").append($add);
    $(".available table").append(newClone);
  });
});

$(".deleteRow").on("click", function() {
  var $add = '<h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer"></h4>';
  var newClone = $(this).parent().parent();
  newClone.find(".deleteRow").remove();
  newClone.find("td:eq(0)").append($add);
  $(".available table").append(newClone);
  $(".addRow").on("click", function() {
    var $delete = '<h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;"></h4>';
    var $clone = $(this).parent().parent();
    $clone.find(".addRow").remove();
    $clone.find("td:eq(0)").append($delete);
    $(".selected table").append($clone);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 available">
    <label>Available Members</label>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer"></h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h6>Cab Swift Two</h6>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer"></h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h6>Dharma</h6>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer"></h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h6>Sahoo</h6>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer"></h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h6>Majhi</h6>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 selected">
    <label>Selected Members</label>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;"></h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h6>Shantanu</h6>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;"></h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h6>Android</h6>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;"></h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h6>ios</h6>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;"></h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h6>Windows</h6>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/30gz3rbt/)

Comment: can you show error?

Comment: check in fiddle, try to add all and then delete all few times, it will stop working after that.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan can you help me solve this issue.

Comment: @AtalShrivastava I added an answer for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

bind event to document and not to table row, as after removing element, bound event is also deleted.

```
$(document).on('click','.addRow'
```

refer updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anilk/30gz3rbt/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nice and simple

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you're dynamically amending the elements, so you need to use delegated event handlers to bind their events:

```
$('.row').on('click', '.addRow', fn);
$('.row').on('click', '.deleteRow', fn);
```

Try this:

```js
$(".row").on("click", '.addRow', function() {
  var $delete = '<h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;"></h4>';
  var $clone = $(this).parent().parent();
  $clone.find(".addRow").remove();
  $clone.find("td:eq(0)").append($delete);
  $(".selected table").append($clone);
  $(".deleteRow").on("click", function() {
    var $add = '<h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer"></h4>';
    var newClone = $(this).parent().parent();
    newClone.find(".deleteRow").remove();
    newClone.find("td:eq(0)").append($add);
    $(".available table").append(newClone);
  });
});

$(".row").on("click", '.deleteRow', function() {
  var $add = '<h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer"></h4>';
  var newClone = $(this).parent().parent();
  newClone.find(".deleteRow").remove();
  newClone.find("td:eq(0)").append($add);
  $(".available table").append(newClone);
  $(".addRow").on("click", function() {
    var $delete = '<h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;"></h4>';
    var $clone = $(this).parent().parent();
    $clone.find(".addRow").remove();
    $clone.find("td:eq(0)").append($delete);
    $(".selected table").append($clone);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 available">
    <label>Available Members</label>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer"></h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h6>Cab Swift Two</h6>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer"></h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h6>Dharma</h6>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer"></h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h6>Sahoo</h6>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer"></h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h6>Majhi</h6>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 selected">
    <label>Selected Members</label>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;"></h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h6>Shantanu</h6>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;"></h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h6>Android</h6>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;"></h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h6>ios</h6>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;"></h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h6>Windows</h6>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div class="row">`. Line 3 in the snippet

Comment: ok cool, i'll accept your answer  but anil kumar answer first